# Display array data in seperate data

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am a student currently made to take a module on computer programming that is supposed to be very basic. Thing is, they don't exactly teach the C++ programming language, but rather bits of it and expect us be able to piece the puzzle together on our own and build a program to hone our "problem thinking skills".

I am looking to display the data, in an array, hidden away in a separate item. 
In other words, the data is in an array, in a separate item known as `data`, while in the main program, I would like to display the data when the user keys in their selection.

For example, in the context of a monthly weather data, how can I make the information, arranged in array, to show when the user enter a certain day. So when the user keys in `21`, it should display the temperature for the 21st of the month, also at the 20th index of the array.

This is what I have done so far:

```
printf("Enter selected month.\n"); 
scanf_s("%c", &month);
if (month==October)
{
    printf("Enter selected date, from 1st to 31st.\n"); 
    scanf_s("%d", &octoberTemperature[i]); 
    printf("%.2f\n", octoberTemperature[i]);
}
```

Any help is very much welcome! :)

Comment: Consider using std::cin or std::getline soon.

Answer (score 1):

In `&octoberTemperature[i]` you have a problem - you are trying to write into an object of the array. You should do it like this:

```
printf("Enter selected month.\n"); 
scanf_s("%c", &month); 
unsigned short day = 0;

if (month==October)
{
    printf("Enter selected date, from 1st to 31st.\n"); 
    scanf_s("%d", &day);         
    printf("%.2f\n", octoberTemperature[day - 1]);
    // as it starts from 0
    // if your array containing the month report starts from 0 then it has to be (day - 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that code of yours u have actually inputed the day u like to find the weather for in a array and printed the same array.
Now do not use the same var to get the day as input

`scanf ("%d",&day)//I assumed day as a var to receive the month day 
  cout<<Octobertemperature[day-1];
    // now if u already have a array containing the data of the weather report..then this will solve your problem.`